# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter cannot be applied to

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

code:

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        recyclerViewadapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RecycleModel, UserViewHolder>(RecycleModel.class, R.layout.recycler_model, UserViewHolder.class, muserDB)
        {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull RecycleModel model) {

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return null;
            }
        };
```

[error on FirebaseRecyclerAdapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kieke.png)

[my gradle file app level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNuIC.png)

Comment: Please post your code and error as text instead of an image. It would also help to include an actual question with a little bit of a description.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<RecycleModel> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<RecycleModel>()
    .setQuery(muserDB, RecycleModel.class)
    .build();

recyclerViewadapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RecycleModel, UserViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull RecycleModel model) {
            // set the model to the holder
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return null;
    }
};
```

`FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` class takes in the last version as an argument in the constructor a `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` object not those 4 arguments anymore.

If you are interested, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.